# Why is $watch not working like I expect - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to watch a value in my controller.  When it changes, I want to send out a broadcast, but I never get inside the `$watch` function.  Here is the function:

```
  $scope.$watch($scope.selectedEncounter, function(selectedEncounter) {
    $scope.$broadcast('selecteRowChange', { encounter: selectedEncounter });
  });
```

Can I watch something attached to the scope?  If so what is the issue I am having with this code.  If not, how do I implement this code to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass either a `function` or a property name to your `$watch` function.

So, in your case, you should just change your code to:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedEncounter', function(value) {
  // ...
});
```

[Here is some more info](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch) from the docs.

Comment: What is the difference between the two?  How does angular know to look on the $scope object for that property?

Comment: What you are doing is to ask Angular to watch for the property with the name equals to the current value of the property `$scope.selectedEncounter`. Basically, let's say you issued `$scope.selectedEncounter = 'test'` before the `$watch` line. So basically, what you're doing is to `$watch` for the `test` property in the current scope. Angular is always going to look at the `$scope` where you called the `$watch`.

Comment: Just adding to the last sentence, if you have `scope1.$watch('prop')`, it's going to `$watch` it in the `scope1`. If you have `$rootScope.$watch`, then you would be watching in the [`$rootScope`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The object you are watching is a complex object. Hence you should set `objectEquality` to `true` in your code as follows:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedEncounter', function(selectedEncounter) {
// ....
}, true);
```

Notice the `true` value as last parameter to the `$scope.$watch` function at the end.